# Should inverseTransform be a static method for a model making predictions

Tags: python

I have a `Model` class that has functions to train and predict using a machine learning model.
Because the data used for training is normalized, the predictions are also normalized and hence need to be inversely transformed.

Should the function `inverseTransform` be part of the `Model` class as a `staticmethod` or should it be outside the class?

Comment: be it where ever you want. I don't get what's the issue with either of them.

Comment: I just wanna know which would be a better design choice...According to me since this method is closely related to the class it should be part of it. But I wanna hear other's opinion on it.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to have it outside the model class

Comment: why? What's the particular reason?

Comment: It worked well for me. That's why, a simple advice

Comment: Then don't write it like `It should be outside of the model class` rather write it like this `It worked for me to have it outside the model class`.

Comment: Oh. Thank you dear. I'll change it right now

Comment: I know both of the ways would work, but I wanna know which one would be better and why?